# Trying to merge certificate and private key

Tags: ssl-certificate

I bought a new certificate from Positive SSL and they asked me for CSR. I generated CSR using a "https://cheapsslsecurity.com/ssltools/csr-generator.php" tool and I got CSR and private key. I send CSR to Positive SSL to generate a certificate and they sent me one certificate. Now I have certificate and private key (in text file). How do I merge and generate "pfx" using this certificate and private key?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use OpenSSL to do this, I am not expert in this but OpenSSL provide lots of features like SSL certificates generation. singing certs, import/export to trust stores/keystores.

Follwoing openssl command one works for you:

## merge

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in pki.crt -out key_out.pfx

[I hope this helps you](http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/keytool-Import-Key-openssl-pkcs12-Command.html)